# Is python code platform independent?

Tags: python, linux, windows, cross-platform

Lets assume a python code written and tested on linux system with python 2.7.1. It utilizes only the default python libraries like: os, itertools, tkinter, csv, collections.

If we take this code and put into a python 2.7.1 on a windows system, will it work fine?

Comment: You can develop for Windows on Linux just fine; just keep your file handling cross-platform (use binary mode when not handling text, use `os.path` to manipulate filenames rather than concatenate manually, etc.).

Comment: However, this question is too broad to be answerable here; if you run into specific issues about Python on Windows, better ask about those.

Comment: I have yet to run any complications, but I wanted know about what others have experienced.

Comment: That's not a question format that fits the Stack Overflow site model, sorry.

Comment: I think now it fits the site format. Thanks for the warning

Comment: No, it is still too broad. You'd have to show us specific code; I can easily write code using the Python default libraries that is platform dependant. To talk about all the ways you can do that is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python bytecode itself is not platform-dependent, assuming a full Python VM implementation.

There are specific modules and functions that are only available on certain platforms, therefore Python source code can be made platform-dependent if it uses these. The documentation specifies if a name is only available on a restricted subset of platforms, so avoiding these will go far to make it platform-independent.

Comment: There may also be other differences that could potentially break a Python application, even when using only the platform-independent functions, e.g., different character restrictions in file names, different file locking behaviour, etc.